# algebraic expression equaling zero: divede by a constant

Tags: linear-algebra

Sorry for this basic question, but:

Suppose you have a simple expression $a+b+c = 0$. Can u divide both sides by $a$ to get $1 + b/a+c/a = 0$ ? This feels wrong, but I don't know why. It might be right?

Comment: If $a\ne0$ then yes and you obtain the equivalent expression $1+\frac ba+\frac ca=0$.

Answer (score 0):

You must assume $a \not= 0$ in order to do that. You can't divide by $0$.

Comment: Och yes, of course, thanks!